# If $z=e^{i\theta}$ is the unit circle what is $z=1-e^{-i\theta}$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, circles

So obviously $z=e^{i\theta}$ is the unit circle. However I am trying to imagine what $z=1-e^{-i\theta}$ will look like. I know that the $1$ will shift it to be centered at $1$ not at the origin but I am not sure what to do with the factor $-e^{-i\theta}$?

My intuition from normal graphing that the first minus next to $e$ will flip it but as the unit circle is symmetric nothing will happen. The second minus in the power I think will reverse the direction of the circle? But again this won't change anything?

Hence it will just be the unit circle at $z=1$. Is this correct or have I got my logic wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right, if you ad that $\theta$ goes from 0 to $2\pi$

Comment: Yes, you've flipped it, reversed the direction and added one, so it's worth having a look at where $\theta=\{0,1/2,1,3/2\}\pi$ correspond to on both circles to get a handle on what's going on.

Comment: If $z=e^{i\theta}$ then $\overline z=e^{-i\theta}$, so $1-e^{-i\theta} = 1 - \overline{z}$ or, in words, take $z$, reflect it over the real axis, point-reflect it across the origin, then translate it right by $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $z=e^{i\theta}$ is the unit circle. The circle is centerat at $z=0$ and evolves anticlockwise from the point $z=1$. Now, $z=1-e^{-i\theta}$ is likewise a circle, albeit one that is centered at $z=1$ and evolves clockwise from the point $z=0$.